# Q_INVOKABLE does not expose method to QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

I want to call C++ method from QML, passing parameters to it. As i understood, i should mark class with macro `Q_OBJECT` and desired public functions with `Q_INVOKABLE`.

Although i did it, i still get in runtime error

```
qrc:/main.qml:42: TypeError: Property 'addFile' of object QObject(0xf20e90) is not a function
```

Here is my `.hpp` and `.cpp` files of the class:

> lib_controller.hpp

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QString>
...

class LibController : public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(decltype(getProgress) progress READ getProgress NOTIFY ProgressChanged)
    public:
        ...

        Q_INVOKABLE
        void addFile(QString from_name, QString to_name);
        ...
};
```

> lib_controller.cpp

```
#include "lib_controller.hpp"
...
void LibController::addFile(QString from_name, QString to_name){
    file_manager = new FileManager(from_name.toUtf8().constData(),
                                   to_name.toUtf8().constData());
}

...
```

> main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlComponent>

#include "lib_controller.hpp"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    // Registration of custom type
    qmlRegisterType<LibController>("com.sort.controller", 0, 1, "LibController");

    ...

    return app.exec();
}
```

> main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import com.sort.controller 0.1

...

     FileDialog {
        id: fileDialog_for_load
        title: "Load file"
        onAccepted: {
           fileDialog_for_save.open()
        }
    }
    FileDialog {
        id: fileDialog_for_save
        title: "Save file"
        onAccepted: {
            var loadPath = fileDialog_for_load.fileUrl.toString();
            loadPath = loadPath.replace(/^(file:\/{2})/,"");

            var savePath = fileDialog_for_save.fileUrl.toString();
            savePath = savePath.replace(/^(file:\/{2})/,"");

            console.log("Save Path:" + savePath)
            libController.addFile(loadPath, savePath)
        }
    }

LibController { id: libController }
```

What i want, is to call function `addFile()` to construct `file_manager` member then it needs to sort new file.

Why is this error happenning? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-dialogs-filedialog.html#fileUrl-prop), `fileUrl` property of `FileDialog` returns a [`url`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-url.html) type which is equivalent to C++ type [`QUrl`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qurl.html) not QString. So you can either:

- Edit your C++ method to take two `QUrl`s.
- Or in your QML pass `.fileUrl.toString()`.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I changed QML code to [this](https://pastebin.com/SGGA4i6u), but error persists. Maybe it returns JS string, not QString? Or problem elsewhere?

Comment: @nonForgivingJesus Please minimize the code and isolate the problem in a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @nonForgivingJesus I tested your code and it works perfectly.

Comment: Well, my project somehow is broken now, i will accept answer then figure out how to make it work again...

Answer (score 1):

in your libcontroller constructor you delete your private member instead of initializing it.

Comment: Oh my gosh, thank you for spotting this error!
But it did not solve problem with `addFile`, problem remains...
I slightly edited end of question to make my intentions clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a component instancing `LibController { id:libController }` in your main.qml.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention this, as thought it would be redundant, but i have this element. Also i edited question